# when my system changed maven project giving error Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, eclipse-classpath

I check out a svn project and run it on my system all things working fine. I give my laptop to IT department to make my Ethernet port working after that when i run that project it is showing

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

My laptop body changed but OS and other software remain same they just shift hard-disk to some other body. All other simple java program running fine except this svn maven project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press Alt+f5 or right click on project go to maven tab and then click on update project. Somehow it works for me :) i wonder if someone can explain.
I also target folder to project to add this first go to
Run Configuration ->Select class -> Classpath tab->click User Entries ->Advance ->add External Folder-> then navigate to target folder of your project.